# PHP - Change only value with '0' to string 'Free'

Tags: php, arrays, json, replace, foreach

I just simplified JSON data i have cause i need only two values from it. I filtered what I need as you can see in code below but in some values are 0 and on output only that zero need to be as new value 'Free'.

Here is the code what i get for now:

```
    $json = '[{"Number":"333567","Cost":0},{"Number":"333568","Cost":7500},{"Number":"333569","Cost":7500}]';
    $options = json_decode($json, true);

        $newArray = [];
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." "."&pound;".$value['Cost'] / 100;
        }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

    print_r($newArray);
```

The results what i got is:

```
Array ( [333567] => 333567 £0 [333568] => 333568 £75 [333569] => 333569 £75 )
```

But i need on output only **£0** be **Free** like this:

```
Array ( [333567] => 333567 Free [333568] => 333568 £75 [333569] => 333569 £75 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." ".($value['Cost'] / 100 == 0 ? 'Free': "&pound;".$value['Cost'] / 100);
```

I hope It will solve your problem

Comment: I try to add span tag around 'Free' and $value['Cost'] / 100 `$newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." "."<br /> <span>".($value['Cost'] / 100 == 0 ? 'Free' : "&pound;".($value['Cost'] / 100)."</span>"); ` but i get nesting span into loop and cant render closed tag, tried many things, but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

you can try **$value['Cost'] / 100 > 0 ? $value['Cost'] : 'free'**
with your code is below

```
    $json = '[{"Number":"333567","Cost":0},{"Number":"333568","Cost":7500},{"Number":"333569","Cost":7500}]';
    $options = json_decode($json, true);

        $newArray = [];
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." "."&pound;".($value['Cost'] / 100 > 0 ? $value['Cost'] : 'free');
        }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

    print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Close enough, but £ is showing with Free, thanks buddy! @Muhammad Atif Akram give right solution.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question correctly, you'll want to replace

```
        $newArray[$value['Number']]= $value['Number']." "."&pound;".$value['Cost'] / 100;
```

with

```
        $priceLabel = ($value['Number'] == 0 ? 'Free' : $value['Number'] . " &pound;");
        $newArray[( $value['Number'] )] = $priceLabel . ($value['Cost'] / 100);
```